# Applying the modifiers to my mesh messed up the model

Tags: modifiers

I have a applied 3 different modifiers to my mesh, and this is the result I'm getting. Any Idea what's causing this problem? I have shrinkwrap, Boolean modifier, and Subdivision. When I choose all and removed doubles, its erasing faces as well.

[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file ?

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=A78z49d0" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/A78z49d0/)

Comment: i am sorry, but i don't get it. What do you want to achieve? your topology is clean. I just moved your objects a bit and deleted the shrinkwrap (i don't know what you want to achieve with that!?) and your topology is looking good...[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otCnx.png

Comment: I want to solidify it, make it more thick.